# Cannot find the FrameLayout element

Tags: eclipse, appium, pydev, ui-automation, python-appium

I am using Pydev in Eclipse to automate an Android app with Appium. I'm not able to click on the element.
FrameLayout has different index [0,1,2] rest everything is same.

I have tried these:

```
driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator("new UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.FrameLayout[@index = '2']\")").click()
```

&

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.LinearLayout[0]/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]").click()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKXFf.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `resource-id` as follows -

```
categoryList = driver.find_element_by_id("categoryListFrameLayout")
for category in categoryList :
    category.click() //do whatever you want to do with the category
```

***Note*** - If you want to specifically use a indexed element form the list you can refer [Accessing the index in Python 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops)